# Rails: prawn PDF to rmagick output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rmagick, prawn

What's wrong with this method? I'm totally stumped. I keep getting this error on the `img.write(res)` line:

```
ArgumentImage no images in this image list
```

Here's the controller method:

```
def convert_to_image
  @document = Document.find(params[:document_id])
  img = Magick::ImageList.new
  pdf = Prawn::Document.generate("tmp.pdf", :margin => 0, :page_size => [398, 398]) do |p|
    res = @document.post_pdf(p)
    img.write(res)
    send_data img
  end
end
```

The `post_pdf` method mentioned above looks like this:

```
def post_pdf(p)
  size = 398
  p.image self.user.logo.path, :width => size
  p.bounding_box([30, 490], :width => size) do
    p.fill_color self.user.colour1
    p.pad_bottom(10) { p.text self.title, :size => 28, :style => :bold }
    p.fill_color '#444444'
  end
  self.components.each do |component|
    p.image component.image_newsletter.path, :width => size
    p.fill_color self.user.colour1
    p.fill_rectangle([0, 20], size, 20)
  end
end
```

Comment: may be you should return something from `post_pdf`? like `p` for example… At the moment it's probably returning `self.components` array.

Comment: I thought Rails automatically returned objects in blocks? I'll check that out.

Comment: `post_pdf(p)` returns last statement which in your case is `self.components.each`. The block you passed to `each` will be `yield` inside `each` scope. Afterward `each` will return the original array. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-each

Functions that take `block` may or may not return results of the `block` so don't rely on it.

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/ilist.html#write

Comment: Still nothing. Tried everything in the `#write` docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED.** It needed:

1.) Ghostscript.

2.) A rewritten method:

```
def create_pdf_image
  @document = Document.find(params[:document_id])
  pdf = Prawn::Document.new
  temp = "#{@document.user.name.downcase.parameterize.underscore}-#{@document.id}"
  @document.post_pdf(pdf)
  pdf.render_file("#{temp}.pdf")
  image = Magick::ImageList.new("#{temp}.pdf")
  image.write("#{temp}.png") { self.quality = 100 }
  send_file "#{temp}.png"
end
```

Might help someone. Apparently rmagick needs ghostscript. My method just wasn't playing either, although the `post_pdf` method remains unchanged.